# Selecting rows based on conditional query on other table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle, customer_details and account_details.

```
  customer_details
  cus_id      rating
  ABC12       RT
  CED34      
  FRTG4       RT
  RET43     
  ERT45       VF

  account_details
  cus_id      account_type      scas_code
  ABC12       SA                0011
  DEF34       CA                009
  CED34       SA                0011
  RET43       FD                008
  ERT45       SA                0011
```

I want `DISTINCT` scas_code from table `account_details` where `rating` should be null from `customer_details` table. My desired result of the query is following

```
  scas_code
  0011
  008
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT scas_code
FROM account_details ad
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer_details cd
              WHERE cd.cus_id = ad.cus_id AND cd.rating IS NULL);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select distinct scas_code
from account_details a inner join customer_details b on a.cust_id=b.cust_id
where rating is null
```